# pusher or websockets always says 403 forbidden

Tags: laravel, vue.js, websocket, pusher, laravel-websockets

**i'm new to websockets and pusher** 
 i did follow the documentation and this tuto https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7MvN0w5BW48 
 but i got this error that says **Unable to retrieve auth string from auth endpoint - received status: 403 from /broadcasting/auth. Clients must be authenticated to join private or presence channels.**

**bootstrap.js**

```
import Echo from "laravel-echo";
let token = localStorage.getItem("token");
window.Pusher = require("pusher-js");

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: "pusher",
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    wsPort: 6001,
    wssPort: 6001,
    forceTLS: false,
    disableStats: true,
    enabledTransports: ["ws", "wss"],
    
    encrypted: false,
   
    auth: {
        headers: {
            Authorization: "Bearer " + token
        }
    }
});
```

**broadcasting.php**

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Broadcaster
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default broadcaster that will be used by the
    | framework when an event needs to be broadcast. You may set this to
    | any of the connections defined in the "connections" array below.
    |
    | Supported: "pusher", "ably", "redis", "log", "null"
    |
    */

    'default' => env('BROADCAST_DRIVER', 'null'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Broadcast Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define all of the broadcast connections that will be used
    | to broadcast events to other systems or over websockets. Samples of
    | each available type of connection are provided inside this array.
    |
    */

    'connections' => [

        'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'useTLS' => true,
                'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                'port' => 6001,
                'scheme' => 'http',
                 'curl_options' => [
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
                ]
            ],
        ],

        'ably' => [
            'driver' => 'ably',
            'key' => env('ABLY_KEY'),
        ],

        'redis' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'default',
        ],

        'log' => [
            'driver' => 'log',
        ],

        'null' => [
            'driver' => 'null',
        ],

    ],

];
```

**channels.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast;
    
Broadcast::channel('App.Models.User.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});
```

**and this a part of createTask.vue**

```
 Echo.join('chat')
    .here((users) => {
        console.log("present user ",users)
    })
    .joining((user) => {
        console.log(user.name);
    })
    .leaving((user) => {
        console.log(user.name);
    })
    .error((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

Comment: This happens when the user is not authenticated. Are you actually authenticated?Also make sure in your env the default broadcaster is pusher

Comment: i'm sure that i'm authenticated as an admin and yes my default broadcaster is pusher .. 
i tried to open this link : http://127.0.0.1:8000/broadcasting/auth 
and i get this error The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.
how can i change the method?